# Localizing a ContextMenu

Tags: .net, wpf, translation

I need to associate a context menu in a WPF user control.

I searched a litte bit and find out that I can do something like

```
<RichTextBox>
    <RichTextBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Command="Cut">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="Images/cut.png" />
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Command="Copy">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="Images/copy.png" />
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Command="Paste">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="Images/paste.png" />
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </RichTextBox.ContextMenu>
</RichTextBox>
```

Now, I have a method that translates a string , say, it is named
`GetTranslation(myString, languageId)`.

How can I use that method to translate Context menu in WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [MarkupExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855815.aspx).